# Horizontal Scrolling in Panorama View

Tags: windows-phone-8

I hava a panorama view with multiple panorama items. In one of these panorama items I have a grid within a ScrollViewer. The grid is too large in terms of width.

The problem is that if the user slides the panorama view gets triggered and changes the panorama item, althrough the the scroll viewer should actually scroll horizontally (until the end of the grid).

However, if the user slides very slowly, the panorama view does not get triggered and only the scrolling takes place. This is the intended behaviour.

Thank you very much

Comment: when i had to do the same thing, [this example](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-disable-pivot-panorama-swipe-gesture-sliding-inside-pivot-item) suited me the most, so take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isHitTestVisible` property.

```
//Disable panorama scrolling
MyPanorama.IsHitTestVisible = false;

//Enable panorama scrolling
MyPanorama.IsHitTestVisible = true;
```

Use this in a `ManipulationStarted` listener. That is, when the use starts scrolling horizontally, you can temporarily make `IsHitTestVisible` to be false.